# Multiple desktop on Zos

Tags: zos

Can someone tell me if it's possible to have more than 2 desktop using ISPF under TSO on z/OS? I can start a new one with the START command but only one so i can have maximal 2 desktop and switch between them with F9.

Answer (score 2):

#### SPF screens

Yes you can have more than 2 'desktops' in ISPF. Sites put different limits on the number; but generally you can have a lot of 'desktops'.

You can use

- **Start** to start a new *screen* or *"desktop"*
- **Swap** command to swap between 2 screens;
- **Swap next** command to scroll through all the *screens* or *"desktops"*
- **Swap List** command to display a list of *"desktops"* (where you can select a *"desktop"*).

You will find PF9 is defined as **SWAP**. You can change that to **Swap next** if you want. Ask people where you work about the options / how they have it set up. You can either copy an existing profile or you are in for a lot of work

You can (and should) change using 0. ?? will let you change the keys.

The **Keys** command will change the pf keys as well. You will will need to do this repeatedly

---

#### ISPF Strucure

In ISPF there are *applications*; each *application* has its own variables, commands and PF-key assignment (pf-Keys are just variables). On top of that there are also key-lists which change the PF-Key assignments further. This allows different applications to have there own variables, commands and pf-keys and not interact with each other.

To put simply, the PF key assignments are held in multiple places. So you need to:

- change keys in 0. whatever
- keep checking keys and change if necessary.
- keep doing this; you will get all the instances eventually.
- make sure you **leave** ispf cleanly; variables only get saved when you exit the ISPF application.

Also google **ISPF keys** and **ISPF KEYLIST** to find more information

---

If you know what you are doing, you can copy the profile from an existing user and save yourself the hassle. That is why I suggested asking people at work.

Some sites setup "standard-ispf-profiles" to give to new-users; yours does not.

---

#### ISPF Profile

There is a PDS (maybe called ispf.profile) allocated to the ISPPROF dd where ISPF stores all its user data. Each *application* has several members associated with it e.g. ISPCMDS holds the **Command definitions** for the ISP application.

Format of members in this dataset

```
 Characters Position   Purpose
   start (1->3/4)      Application name
   last 4              Purpose
```

Comment: I set swap prev and swap next it works during 2-3 Times but then I can only switch again between 2 'Desktops'

Comment: ISPF has an entity called keylists, and unfortunately different screens have different keylists (for example, the Edit Entry Panel, SDSF, and the Editor all have different keylists). And there's no easy way to update all keylists to have same defintiion, nor would you want them to. Every time you find a case where you are going back and forth between the same two screens, you will have to check the keylist on each one, and then update the one that has PF9 set to just "swap".

Answer (score 0):

U can use START quite a few times.

Try the command SWAPBAR ON or SWAPBAR OFF too.
Then you can put your cursor on the screen you want and press enter.
You can even give your screen names with the command SCRNAME MYSCREEN1 etc.

SWAPBAR is persistent also when you logoff. SCRNAME will be lost once the screen is closed, so I usually use the generated screen names as you can imagine mostly which screens they are.

Answer (score 0):

A lazy way is to set SWAPBAR ON so that you'd be able to see all started screens, then on the command line you can enter the number of the screen you want to swap to and PF9 will swap to exactly that screen (assuming it's configured as SWAP).